# How can I specify a CellRange of variable length in DataNitro?

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I am creating a script and part of it requires a list of names from a cell range to be stored as a list. I need the list to store as many names as are added to the cellrange however it must not store the values of empty cells.
If I simply use a longer range than is necessary like so:

```
names = CellRange("C10:C99999").value
```

then my final script will iterate through all the empty values which is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some searching through the DataNitro documentation I found `.vertical` property which "returns the values of the cells starting with the cell it’s called from, and ending in the last non-empty cell in the same column."
So in my example this would mean:

```
names = Cell("C10").vertical
```